# React Native State is empty, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My app renders messages. App fetches messages from API and save it in state. Provide you my component code:

```
const MessagesScreen = () => {

     const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

     useEffect(() => {
        getMessages();
        processMessages();
      }, []);

      async function getMessages() {
         try {
        
            let request = {
                token: auth,
                offset: offset,
                limit: limit,
            };
    
            const response = await network('my URL API', request);

            
            setMessages([...messages, ...response]); // or even setMessages(response);

            console.log(response);// IS NOT EMPTY, FILLED WITH DATA FROM API
            console.log(messages);  // IS EMPTY [], BUT I JUST CALLED setMessages BEFORE
   

          }
          catch (err) {
             console.log(err)
          }
        }

        function processMessages() {
             console.log(messages);  // IS EMPTY [], BUT I NEED TO PROCESS MESSAGES
             ...
        }

        return (<FlatList data={messages}/>)
}
```

As you can see, `messages` is empty array everywhere. How can I fix it? Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

From docs
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate
`setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later.` 
This why your  `console.log(messages)` is showing an empty array

Comment: Thanks. So, is there any solution in my case? I have to access `messages` in my code.

Comment: add an messages argument to `processMessages` function and then update the state from inside the function.